# How can I run a stratified glm.nb on a mids object in R?

Tags: r, r-mice

I have a mids object output from MICE that I need to run a series of stratified negative binomial models (glm.nb()) on. The stratification variable ("pressure") is itself imputed. The below code subsets the data within the glm.nb() function.

Is this the correct approach to run the stratified models?

```
library("mice") # For MI
library("MASS") # For glm.nb()

set.seed(09212020)

df <- data.frame("ethnicity" = sample(1:4, 50, replace = TRUE) ,
                  "education" = sample(1:4, 50, replace = TRUE) ,
                  "age" = sample(50:90, 50, replace = TRUE) ,
                  "pressure" = sample(0:12, 50, replace = TRUE),
                  "outcome_rate" = sample(0:6, 50, replace = TRUE),
                  "exposure_quart" = sample(1:4, 50, replace=TRUE,
                                            prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05)))


# Insert NAs for MICE
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.85, 0.15), 
                                                 size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))

# Run MICE
imp <- mice(data = df, m = 2, maxit = 1)

# Attempt to run stratified model on the mids object
# This is the portion I'm seeking to have confirmed/updated
m1 <- with(imp, (glm.nb(outcome_rate ~ exposure_quart + ethnicity + education + age + pressure, 
                        subset = imp$imp$pressure < 9)))

m1
```